# Need help with conversion of number to text while adding commas and $

Tags: formula-field

I have this lovely formula field:

```
"$" & if(TotalPrice<1000,text(round(TotalPrice,2)), 
text(floor(TotalPrice/1000))&","&right(text(floor(TotalPrice)),3))
```

That does a great job. It takes a number value and makes it text. It also adds a "," and a "$". It works great for any "numbers" from 1000 to 999999. Over a million, not so much. We obviously have to add another ",".

My thought is that we need another if statement, but I cannot seem to get one to work. Can anyone assist?

The end result is anything from 1000-999999 we need one comma. Anything over 1000000, we need two.

Comment: "$" & IF(TotalPrice<1000,
         text(round(TotalPrice,2)),
         IF (TotalPrice < 1000000,
             text(floor(TotalPrice/1000))&","&right(text(floor(TotalPrice)),3),
             text(floor(TotalPrice/1000000))&","&right(text(floor(TotalPrice/1000)),3)&","&right(text(floor(TotalPrice)),3)
            )
         )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a great blog post on this topic [here](http://appirio.com/category/tech-blog/2010/02/displaying-currencies-in-a-sfdc-formula-field-or-visualforce/) which suggests the following formula:

> ```
> IF( 
>   someCurrencyField__c >= 1000000, 
>   TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c / 1000000)) & ",", 
>   "") & 
> IF( 
>   someCurrencyField__c >= 1000, 
>   RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c / 1000)), 3) & ",", 
>   "") & 
> RIGHT(TEXT(FLOOR(someCurrencyField__c)), 3) & "." & 
> IF( 
>   MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1) * 100 < 10, 
>   "0" & TEXT(ROUND(MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1), 2) * 100), 
>   TEXT(MIN(ROUND(MOD(someCurrencyField__c , 1), 2) * 100, 99)) 
> )
> ```